# Cant make headphones work

Tags: sound, headphones

I'm new to this whole linux stuff. But when I plug in my headphones, I don't hear anything from it.

I have 2 plugs for headphones and the second is broken because there is a broken piece of earphone in there. So I tried plugging it in, in the 2nd plug and I downloaded PulseAudio Volume COntrol and when it says Line Out (Plugged In), Speakers (Unavailable) and Headphones (Unplugged) And when I try to test the sound for Line Out there wasn't any sound coming out.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Notebook? If so, the 2nd plug will most likely be the input plug for microphone and if the first plug is blocked by a broken earphone piece you can't use line out anymore...

If you are on a Desktop PC with more than one output then you can have a look in the system audio options...

Comment: Yea, It's a notebook computer. But it has 1 specific for microphone which works and two others which is for headphones. It has a small picture next the the plugs.

Comment: okay, did you looked in the audio settings under the output tab for the two different outputs? Are there two outputs shown?

Comment: I think this would be better suited as a comment rather than an answer...

Comment: It only shows Line Out, no speakers, no headphones..

Comment: i need 50 reputations to comment but i can answer... (it's strange in my opinion)